# CSRF attacks and Websockets

Tags: javascript, websocket

Is `websockets` vulnerable to CSRF attacks, and how can one do this if `Websocket` does authentication like login ?

Answer (score 2):

I think **YES**.

If somehow the attacker initialized a socket connection from the client-side and sends message then yes, the CSRF attack is possible.

Of course, this is **TRUE ONLY IF YOU ARE USING COOKIE BASED AUTHENTICATION.**

As CSRF attacks use cookies, which are automatically sent by browser with the request, and the request gets authenticated.

If you are using cookies to authenticate the request and connection, then yes CSRF attack is possible.

**To avoid these attacks, it is better to use TOKEN BASED Authentication like [JWT](https://medium.com/@maison.moa/using-jwt-json-web-tokens-to-authorize-users-and-protect-api-routes-3e04a1453c3e).**

*`No Cookie-based authentication == No need for CSRF protection.`*

here are a few helpful links regarding **AUTHENTICATION**:

[cookies vs token authentication](https://dzone.com/articles/cookies-vs-tokens-the-definitive-guide)

[REST api authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506843/rest-api-authentication-for-web-app-and-mobile-app)

[Do you need CSRF protection?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/170388/do-i-need-csrf-token-if-im-using-bearer-jwt)

Comment: I find this problematic.  We are saying that token based authentication is better than cookie based authentication, but the first article you link talks about storing the JWT in localStorage.  Why is that better?  You've mitigated CSRF but you introduced XSS.  I think "defense-in-depth" is a better answer than saying one method is "better" than another.

Comment: Most of the modern framework comes with input-sanitization which prevents XSS attacks themselves. But yes, we should be aware of such attacks.

Comment: I agree with you --- ' "defense-in-depth" is a better answer than saying one method is "better" than another.' We must choose that approach which is best for our implementation and needs.

Comment: where to store JWT token? we must store it in persistent storage and send it through authorization header, even if the attacker gets hold of it, he can't read data stored into it.

Comment: Here is a good article on the subject... don't be put off by the subject, it is not a hit job on JWT's: http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/

Answer (score 0):

I hope this isn't too late being a year old, but you can check the Origin header in addition to HttpOnly session cookies. Ref: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76816/preventing-csrf-attacks-against-websocket-communications

Answer is also influenced by: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/security.html

Token based authentication imo should be reserved for mobile applications.

Comment: Keep in mind that non-browser clients can easily set the `Origin` header to any arbitrary value, it should not be relied on for security purposes.

Comment: @MattSanders But doesn't CSRF only happen inside the browser? The one with the authentication cookies? Outside of a browser, with locally running software, anything can happen.